# Derivative of a special double integrale in the calculus of variation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, convolution, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $u$ be a real function defined on $[0, T]$ and the functional 
$$V(u) = \iint\limits_{[0,T]^2}f(x,y)u(x)u(y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
and $f(x,y)$ is symmetric , continuous and can be writen on this form  $f(x,y)=h(x-y)$

I would like to maximise this fonctional under an isoperimetric constraint :
$\int^{T}_{0}u(x)dx= L$

the ideas is to use lagrange multiplier i.e : $J(u)=V(u)+\lambda \int^{T}_{0}u(x)dx $

The functional derivative
$$<\delta J(u), v>= \iint\limits_{[0,T]^2}f(x,y)[u(x)v(y) + u(y)v(x)]\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+\lambda \int^{T}_{0}v(x)dx  $$
as $f$ is symmetric 
$$<\delta J(u), v>= 2\iint\limits_{[0,T]^2}[f(x,y)u(x)v(y)]\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+\lambda \int^{T}_{0}v(x)dx  $$
Now i would like to obtain a weak "Euler lagrage" Equation,so i do this  :
$$<\delta J(u), v>= 2\int_{[0,T]} \left( \int_{[0,T]} (f(x,y)u(x)+\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} )\, dx \right) v(y)\, dy =0 \quad\hbox{for all    } v $$

now by the Fondamentale Lemma of the calculus of variation, this implies :
$$\int_{[0,T]} (f(x,y)u(x))dx+\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}=0 \quad\hbox{ a.e } $$
wich means $$h*u+\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} =0. \quad \hbox{(1)}$$
I have two Question 
1) is my computations correct?

2) how can I solve the equation (1)?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems $\pi$ should be $T$.